# synchronize different user sessions when events happened in PHP

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, synchronization

I’m writing a social networking application and I want to synchronize different user sessions.

My context is following:

userA is logged and has an array of his contacts in session.
userB is logged and has an array of his contacts in session.

userA adds userB as a contact.
So, Contact table (DB) sees a new record
And userA has an update of his array of contacts (easy because the event happens on userA navigation side)

My need is following:

I want now to synchronize automatically userB’s session so that his array of contacts is refreshed
without doing a sql query to check the contacts table (db). I want that in order to avoid making too many sql queries to check that.

Do you have any suggestions?

I’m using CodeIgniter (PHP) and the session is managed with database.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without doing a sql query to check the contacts table. Even if you hold your sessions in sql table you still have to query for the data

Answer (score 0):

You want to update a copy of the data (userAs session) without refering to the master set of data. This is just not going to work.

With it's shared nothing architecture, this is going to be hard to implement in PHP.

The only sensible way to achieve this in anything approaching realtime is to maintain a semaphore for each current user session - and set that semaphore when the session data should be re-loaded. And at that point you *must* read the data from the database.

Much of this could be done within the session handler - which is probably the most sensible place to handle it - but you need to be aware that the semaphore is therefore volatile and code it appropriately (e.g. using optimistic locking around reading/writing the semaphore).

Comment: But, you mean the semaphore is a variable in session? If yes, this is the same problem, I suppose I need to query the database regularly... I dont think this is a best practice. I could maybe query the database if a user visits a sensitive page where I need a up to date array list of contacts but I don't like this.

Comment: "you mean the semaphore is a variable in session" - no - since the session should not be writeable by processes operating on behalf of other users - but it might be held in the same place as the session, and read by the sesison handler - in which *you are doing no more I/O per request* than you would have been in the absence of the semaphore.